# Youtube's onPlayerReady event not firing when called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I am using two video modules on a webpage. Both use the YT-api in the same way. Both work without any problems individually, but when I use the two modules next to eachother, only one (the first one in the DOM) proceeds to onPlayerReady(), the next one doesn't. It does seem to load the video's correctly (the js-vid div get's replaced with an iframe) in every case.

If I add initYoutubeVideo() to the bottom of the function, it does proceed, but then I do get errors for example 'Uncaught TypeError: player.getDuration is not a function'

My code seems pretty standard

```js
function ytVideo(element) {
var _$element = $(element); 
var $vid = _$element.find('.js-vid');
var player = $vid[0];

  function initYoutubeVideo() {

        player = $vid[0];
        // e.g. <div class="video js-vid" data-video-id="id-of-yt-video-here"></div>

        var playerParams = {
            // Params
            playerVars: {
            // Vars
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        }
        
        player = new YT.Player(player, playerParams);

    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        console.log('Nothing');
        console.log(player);
        var length = player.getDuration();
        // Etc
}
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container"> <!-- element -->
<div class="video js-vid" data-video-id="id-of-yt-video-here"></div> <!-- $vid[0] -->
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `$vid` defined?

Comment: I'll update the code

Comment: I've updated the code. Everything is loaded in a "big" function. The vars are on top of that function. I set 'player' two times, it doesn't seem to matter if I remove the second one.

Comment: You're not calling `initYoutubeVideo()` in the `ytVideo()` function? Also, which library is `YT` a reference to?

Comment: initYoutubeVideo() is called and is fired everytime. I just deleted a lot of "irrelevant" code because it proceeds untill the onPlayerReady(). YT is standard Youtube Api I supposed.